# LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 9, column 27 (byte 308) after

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Am executing below logstash config file to get oracle table into elasticsearch, Please find my below logstash config file with JDBC input plugin.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\1SearchEngine\data\ojdbc8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
    jdbc_user => "demo"
    jdbc_password => "1234567"
    statement => 'select vp.id, 
     LISTAGG(vp.code,',')within GROUP (order by vp.code) "CODE", 
     LISTAGG(vbl.product_id,',')within GROUP (order by vbl.product_id) "PRODUCT_ID",
     LISTAGG(vbl.type,',')within GROUP (order by vbl.type) "TYPE" 
     from product vp,PRODUCT_LINK vbl 
     where vp.id = vbl.product_id 
     group by id,vbl.product_id,vbl.type'
 }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "replacement"
  }
}
```

While executing the config file am getting the below error

```
 Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 9, column 27 (byte 308) after \tinput {\n\t  jdbc
```

Am using logstash 6.2.4 version

it is throwing error in the first single quote `select vp.id,LISTAGG(vp.code,',')`

Comment: Are you shure that the statement is legal Oracle SQL? It seems this is an Oracle error, not a JDBC error.
Try it out in PL/SQL-Developer or any other tool directly on the database.

Comment: Its perfectly executing in SQL developer., after forming the query in developer then only am trying to execute here.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the quotes? from here: https://www.tekstream.com/oracle-error-messages/ora-00923-from-keyword-not-found-where-expected/ ... if you used quotation marks in an alias, make sure that they have properly enclosed the alias and that they are double quotation marks.

Comment: I made some changes, now it showing different error , now error in the first single quote `select vp.id, LISTAGG(vp.code,',')` but same query working fine in developer

Comment: I think you should use double quotes for the whole statement and then only single quotes within the statement

Comment: if i give whole statement surrounded by double quites `""` and rest all single quote `''` then its throwing ` Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` exception

Comment: You shouldn't put big queries inside of a config file instead save the query to file and add path to the query instead of a statement, `statement_filepath => "PATH"`. Inside of your statement file use only double quotation marks.

Comment: @MichaelDz - If i save the query in file and giving the path in `satement_filepath => "PATH"` am getting this error `[2018-06-15T17:58:17,902][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:\nORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor\n "}`

Comment: If i place the query in config file itself means., am not getting this error.

Comment: That's actually good sign, we might have solved the first issue you've reported. There's probably something wrong with `jdbc_connection_string`. Can you actually log in to the database using provided credentials? I'm sure that there is something wrong with SID/Service name. Try lower case letters `xe` or `/` instead of `:` at the end.

Comment: am able to connect via sql developer and all. and if i gave my query directly in config file., its connecting and execuiting., but it showing error in query not the connectivity error.

Comment: How can you know if it is connecting? Maybe it's first checking query syntax and not even trying connecting because of an error. Try some very simple query and you will know for sure.

Comment: @MichaelDz - its working with simple queries, am able to load data into elasticsearch

Comment: Didn't you make a typo `satement_filepath => "PATH"`?